# VBA, another overflow error

Tags: vba

In the code below, why do I get an overflow error at x = i ^ 3 ?

```
    Dim i As Long, x As Long, s As Long, k As Byte

    Do
        i = i + 1
        x = i ^ 3

    Dim n As Long, j As Long, b As String
        b = CStr(x)
        n = Len(b)
        For j = 1 To n
            s = s + Val(Mid$(b, j, 1))
        Next

        If s = i Then
            k = k + 1
            Debug.Print i
        End If
    Loop Until k = 6
```

When I take out the part of code that starts with Dim n as long and ends with the for loop, and turn it into an auxiliary function, then the remaining code works (that is, no overflow error at x = i ^ 3).

Comment: Your code is so obscure that it is hard to see just how much `i` is incremented. There is a limit to the size of a number that a `Long` can hold. Once `i` exceeds 1290, `i^3` overflows a long. In my response to your other question I suggested that you need to use the decimal subtype of a variant to do what you seem to be trying to do. That recommendation still holds.

Comment: Also -- note that you are never resetting `s` in successive passes through the loop. If your intention is to get the sum of the digits in `x` then maybe you should rest `s` to 0 before the for loop.

Comment: Your comment that I need to reset s to 0 before the loop, I think that solves my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: You are mistaken. When I run your code I get the same overflow error. Hovering the cursor over the `i` reveals that its value when the error is triggered is `1291`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic) - MSDN - Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) are not the data types used in the VBA [VBA Data Types](http://cis.poly.edu/~mleung/CS394/f06/VBA/essentialElements/dataTypes.html)

Visual Basic Long is 8 bytes with a min/max value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 through 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

VBA Long is 4 bytes with a min/max value of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.

> 1291 ^ 3 = 2,151,685,171 'Runtime Error 6 Overflow